# stristr return value only if matching the starting characters?

Tags: php, string, string-comparison

```
stristr($haystack, $needle)
```

This function will take string $haystack, look through it to find string $needle and if found will return the entire value of haystack.

I want to return the value of haystack ONLY if $needle matches any number of values in order from the start.

For example, stristr will return $haystack in all the examples, but what I want is below:

```
$haystack = "foo"
$needle =   "oo"
return false;

$haystack = "foo"
$needle =   "f"
return $haystack;

$haystack = "foo"
$needle =   "o"
return false;

$haystack = "foo"
$needle =   "fo"
return $haystack;
```

It seems to me like this may be something built into php, but I can't find anything in the docs.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a new function for this and use `substr` or `strpos` in it, like:

```
function matchBegining($needle, $haystack)
{
    if(substr($haystack, 0, strlen($needle)) === $needle)
    {
        return $haystack;
    }
    return false;
}
```

This will return `$haystack` if matches and `false` if not.

The if statement with `strpos`:

```
 if (strpos($haystack, $needle) === 0) {
```